# Converting hex to ASCII with perl -e

Tags: perl, hex, ascii

I want to print the ASCII equivalent of hex in `perl -e` in one line.

```bash
perl -e "print 0x41;"
```

I'm getting `65`, but I want the output to be `A`

How can I convert from hex to ASCII in just one line command.

Comment: print chr(0x41);

Answer (score 7):

A few ways:

```bash
$ perl -e 'printf "%c\n", 0x41'
A
$ perl -E 'say pack("c", 0x41)'
A
$ perl -E 'say chr(0x41)'
A
```

Comment: `pack("W", 0x41)` would be the equivalent of the other two.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a hex string to ASCII, you can use Perl's `pack` function:

```
$ perl -le 'print pack("H*", "0x41");'
```

Where:
**-l**: enables automatic line-ending processing
**-e**: to specify the Perl code directly on the command line
**H***: format specifier with pack function

Output:

```
A
```